# how to store and manage the access_token and refresh_token for Oauth2 (React JS)?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0

I have an API Rest created in Django and Django Rest Framework.
I implemented the Oauth2 protocol using the OAuth Toolkit library.
The backend is built and working.
I have questions about how to maintain and manage tokens in the front-end made in React.
The access_token expires every 10 days, so I need to make a request to renew the access_token using refresh_token.
The big issue is that when creating the React build, even using environment variables, with each token renewal, I will have to generate the build again.
Is there any way to do this differently, without having to generate a new build every time the token is renewed?

Comment: How are you storing the tokens on the frontend.?. IF the token expires, just call the backend api again to get new token!

Answer (score 0):

To store and manage OAuth2 access and refresh tokens in a React.js application:

Use secure storage options like localStorage or sessionStorage for access tokens.
Never expose refresh tokens on the client side; store them securely on the server.
Implement token expiration handling and a refresh mechanism.
Use HTTPS to ensure secure communication.
An example using React hooks involves creating a context and using localStorage for storing the access token.

Hope it will helps you.